# Defining a string using custom shortcodes

Tags: php, string, comparison

In a PHP application I am using they provide the ability to pull data using shortcodes such as #_CATEGORYID.  When using `$cat_id = '#_CATEGORYID';`  and echoing `$cat_id` the correct numeric digit is returned, 55 in this case.  When `var_dump` on `$cat_id` it returns a string count of 12 which is how many characters #_CATEGORYID specifically is.

I would like to use a comparison operator to display something `if ($cat_id == 55)` but the comparison wont work due to the string length being 12 characters.

Any idea on how to compare something like this?

Comment: You need to share the source-code of that PHP appliaction so that your question can be answered.

Comment: Shortcodes? Is it related to WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast $cat_id to an int `if ((int) $cat_id == 55)`